# C# Write / Read file, should I use a lock

Tags: c#, winforms, file, timer

I need advice whether or not using a lock (ReaderWriterLockSlim).

A user interacts on screen, and data can be saved into a file :

```
XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyFile));
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
xmlserializer.Serialize(fs, this);
fs.Close();
```

In parallel, I have a timer (thus same thread, System.Windows.Forms.Timer), which checks this same file size and sends it to a server if modified. 
I'll use File.ReadAllBytes as this is a rather small file.

Should I use a lock since writing filestream takes some time ?

I wonder if the timer can cause problem (I don't have a clear understanding if it preempts).

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Whoa, take a step back here. Why on earth would you use `ReadAllBytes` to get the length of a file instead of `FileInfo.Length` ?  If I ask you how many pages long a book is, you don't have to read the book to find out! Is it because you need to send the bytes to the server?

Comment: Is this a UI timer? That is, is the timer posting events back to the UI thread?

Comment: Suppose there is another process entirely that is *also* writing to the file. Your idea of using a reader-writer lock isn't going to work in that scenario! You don't need a cross-thread lock, you need a cross-process lock. **Files already provide that**, which means that **you need to make sure you correctly handle the scenario where the file is locked when you attempt to read or write it**.  Have you done that?

Comment: I'm sending the file to the server using File.ReadAllBytes(path) (not for checking file size). So first I checkfile size, then I send the file via this function.

Comment: And what if the file has changed its *contents* but not its *size*? This whole thing seems very dodgy to me.

Comment: No there is no other process, not even other thread, just main thread and a timer (same winform)

Comment: Well if there is no other process and no other thread then why do you need to check *anything* to know if the file is altered? **You're doing the altering, so you know**.  And if everything is on one thread then why would you think you need a thread lock? If you put a thread to sleep *waiting for itself to complete a job* then obviously it will sleep forever! This question is confusing.

Comment: And if the writing will take some time, and it is happening on the UI thread, then how are you not hanging the UI?  This whole thing sounds like it needs to be redesigned.

Comment: If you know what text you are writing *into* the file, then why do you need to read that text back *out* of the file to send it to the server?  You have the text in hand; just send it!

Comment: Funny how you did not reply to my request but you're questioning what I was doing. Have a look at the crystal clear answer below.
The file is only growing, thus file size is my only matter.
You're right I know the file is altered since in same thread, but I already have this timer running (used for my TCP socket and other small things for the TCP connection) so I'd rather use this timer to send my file regularly rather on a time base or if it has grown too much.
About not hanging the UI, I did not want to ask about asynch writing as this was a different matter (and my users are slow!)

Comment: You're the one who said that you want *any advice*, and I'm giving you *lots of good advice*. If you didn't want advice, don't ask for it! It sounds like there are numerous problems with this design that you might not have thought of; now would be a good time to think carefully about them.

Comment: My advice was about using a lock. The perfect answer was the one below. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If the given answer is acceptable then please mark it as accepted so that others know to not look at your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WinForms an event never interrupts a running method running in the same thread (i.e. in the UI thread). Any `timer_Tick` (from `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) will be delayed until the serializing code is finished.

(I assume that you are not using async calls.)

You can read the file size directly from the `FileStream` before closing it.

```
var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyFile));
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
    xmlserializer.Serialize(fs, this);
    Console.WriteLine(fs.Length); // <=========
} // The using-statement automatically closes fs
```

---

If you need to know whether the file changed in another routine, why don't you just use a flag?

```
public static bool FileHasChanged { get; set; }

...

var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyFile));
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
    xmlserializer.Serialize(fs, this);
}
FileHasChanged = true;
```

In the other routine (`timer_Tick` I think):

```
if (MyFile.FileHasChanged) {
    //TODO: Send file to server.
    MyFile.FileHasChanged = false;
}
```

Since everything is running in the same thread, no locking is required.

---

Another question is whether you really need a file or whether you could just write to a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.7.2) and then use this memory stream to send the data to the server. If you still need the file, you could write to it using the same memory stream and serialize only once. The memory stream would replace the Boolean flag for the communication between the two routines. After sent to the server, the memory stream would be set to `null` after calling `Dispose()` (instead of `MyFile.FileHasChanged = false;`).

That would be more in the sense of Eric Lippert's comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not sure about that. 
I feel stupid being able to deal with TCP sockets for communication (thus locks are useful) but not so sure about this simple timer...
Again as I wrote in another comment, I use File.Readallbytes for sending the file via socket (if size different) not for checking file size. My bad english, I wanted to just note which read function I was using.

Comment: Thanks for all valuable comments and advice.